# Minimize the error of distances by placing points

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I have a set of 2d variables which I'm assigning, let's call them `x[1], x[2], ..., x[n]`.

I also have a set of (n)(n-1)/2 **known** distances, let's call them `d[1,2], d[1,3], ..., d[n-2,n-1], d[n-2,n], d[n-1,n]`.

My goal is to assign values to all `x` such that the sum of squared differences between `||x[i]-x[j]||` and `d[i,j]` is minimized.  (This implies that for each i,j, I want the distance between `x[i]` and `x[j]` to closely approximate `d[i,j]`.)  If it's simpler I could force the squared distance between `x[i]` and `x[j]` to closely approximate `d[i,j]^2`.

Is there a name for this problem?  I feel convinced it should be possible to formulate it more "simply" than writing out the sum `((x[1]-x[2])^2 - d[1,2]^2)^2 + ((x[1]-x[3])^2 - d[1,3]^2)^2...` as an objective function and minimizing it using any generic optimization method.  But thus far it's eluded me.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Euclidean distance problem, a classical hard problem.